# Awesomium WPF WebControl Setting .Source property does not work

Tags: wpf, web-controls, awesomium

ALl:

Hopefully someone is using Awesomium in WPF as I am doing now.

I have a WPF control containing a WebControl which I want to dynamically set the source

However, it seems that setting .Source does not work at all. It will always stay in the page that the source is set the very first time.

Version I am using now is Awesomium 1.7 Rc3

Basically I updated the sample code provided in Awesomium 1.7 Rc3 sdk, project

Xaml Part:

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Click="Button_Click" Content="Navigate" Width="500" Height="100"/>
    <awe:WebControl Grid.Row="1"
        Name="webControl" 
        Source="http://stackoverflow.com"            
        ShowCreatedWebView="OnShowNewView" Width="900" Height="1000"/>            
</Grid>
```

Code Behind is like

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        WebCore.Initialize( new WebConfig() { LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose } );
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClosed( EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnClosed( e );
        webControl.Dispose();
        WebCore.Shutdown();
    }

    private void OnShowNewView( object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( !webControl.IsLive )
            return;
        e.Cancel = true;
        webControl.Source = e.TargetURL;
    }

    static int i = 0;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            this.webControl.Source = new Uri("http://yahoo.com.sg");
        else
            this.webControl.Source = new Uri("http://google.com.sg");

        i++;
    }
```

When I click the button, I suppose that webcontrol should toggle between yahoo and google, 
but nothing happens when I click.

Comment: .Source should be what triggers navigation. Could you post some code so we can see the context of your usage?

Comment: @HotN i updated the code, can you help? thanks. Currently i use WebControl in Win Form hosted in WPF, but i think it is not a good idea as i rather use the native WPF one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're code is correct and is using the API as the documentation instructs. However, this turns out to be a bug with Awesomium 1.7RC3. See [this post](http://forums.awesomium.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=96&p=211&hilit=loadurl#p211) in the support forums.

You can still use [WebControl.LoadURL()](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_7_rc3/sharp_api/) for this release.